# Remove duplicates in a list of tuples based on max value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set, tuples

Suppose I have a list of `tuples` like this:

```
[('Machine1', 88), ('Machine2', 90), ('Machine3', 78), ('Machine1', 90), ('Machine3', 95)]
```

And I want to filter the list such that I only have the highest values pertaining to each `tuple` pairing. So in this example the filtered list would be:

```
[('Machine2', 90),('Machine1', 90), ('Machine3', 95)]
```

I basically want to remove duplicates by the highest value. I know `set` only removes exact duplicates so I won't be able to do that here. I thought another method I could use would be to use a `dictionary` and update it while iterating through the list if a higher value was seen. However, what is a more pythonic way to approach this?

Comment: The dict is a good approach; so is any data structure that would give you a `groupby` operator.  Stack Overflow is not a design site -- give it a try and let's see your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution using `collections.defaultdict`. The idea is to iterate your list of tuples and append to lists. Then use `zip` with `map` + `max` to create the desired result.

```
from collections import defaultdict

L = [('Machine1', 88), ('Machine2', 90), ('Machine3', 78),
     ('Machine1', 90), ('Machine3', 95)]

d = defaultdict(list)

for name, num in L:
    d[name].append(num)

res =  list(zip(d, map(max, d.values())))
```

**Result**

```
[('Machine1', 90), ('Machine2', 90), ('Machine3', 95)]
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution with simple `dict`

```
d = {}
for machine, value in l:
    d[machine] = max(d.get(machine, -float('inf')), value)
print(list(d.items()))
```

Outputs

```
[('Machine1', 90), ('Machine2', 90), ('Machine3', 95)]
```

---

Using `pandas` (for fun)

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(l).groupby(0).max().to_dict()[1].items()
[('Machine1', 90), ('Machine2', 90), ('Machine3', 95)]
```

Comment: Can always use `inf`, will edit :) Good suggestion !

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to use the groupby operator in itertools:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> [ (k, max( list(zip(*g))[1])   ) for k,g in it.groupby(sorted(data), key=lambda m: m[0])]
```

Remember that the data is sorted, so you could also do:

```
>>> [ (k, list(zip(*g))[1][-1]   ) for k,g in it.groupby(sorted(data), key=lambda m: m[0])]
```